# How to achieve capturing groups in flex lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, capturing-group

I wanted to match for a string which starts with a '#', then matches everything until it matches the character that follows '#'. This can be achieved using capturing groups like this: `#(.)[^(?1)]*(?1)`(**EDIT** this regex is also erroneous). This matches `#$foo$`, does not match `#%bar&`, matches first 6 characters of `#"foo"bar`.

But since flex lex does not support capturing groups, what is the workaround here?

Comment: Which regex library did you have in mind which accepts `[^(?1)]` as a valid character class? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I just thought of it. Isn't it valid?

Comment: All the regex libraries which I know which allow backreferences only allow them as strings to match, not as members of a character class. But there are a lot of regex libraries, and I can't claim to know all of them.

Comment: Yep, Sorry for that. I too didn't find any.  So this particular problem is unsolved in all existing/known libraries. :)

Comment: In most regex libraries, you'd use a non-greedy match instead of an exclusion. (But (f)lex doesn't have non-greedy matches either.) So you would be able to write `#(.)(.*?)\1`. (https://regex101.com/r/bYnaPq/1) (Regex101 is very cool, but it is not at all useful for (f)lex.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, (f)lex does not support capturing groups, and it certainly doesn't support backreferences.

So there is no simple workaround, but there are workarounds. Here are a few possibilities:

1. You can read the input one character at a time using the `input()` function, until you find the matching character (but you have to create your own buffer to store the characters, because characters read by `input()`  are not added to the current token). This is not the most efficient because reading one character at a time is a bit clunky, but it's the only interface that (f)lex offers. (The following snippet assumes you have some kind of expandable stringBuilder; if you are using C++, this would just be replaced with a `std::string`.)

   ```c
   #.   { StringBuilder sb = string_builder_new();
          int delim = yytext[1];
          for (;;) {
            int next = input();
            if (next == delim) break;
            if (next == EOF ) { /* Signal error */; break; }
            string_builder_addchar(next);
          }
          yylval = string_builder_release();
          return DELIMITED_STRING;
        }
   ```
2. Even less efficiently, but perhaps more conveniently, you can get (f)lex to accumulate the characters in `yytext` using `yymore()`, matching one character at a time in a start condition:

   ```c
   %x DELIMITED
   %%
     int delim;

   #.              { delim = yytext[1]; BEGIN(DELIMITED); }
   <DELIMITED>.|\n { if (yytext[0] == delim) { 
                       yylval = strdup(yytext);
                       BEGIN(INITIAL);   
                       return DELIMITED_STRING;
                     }
                     yymore();
                   }
   <DELIMITED><<EOF>> { /* Signal unterminated string error */ }
   ```
3. The most efficient solution (in (f)lex) is to just write one rule for each possible delimiter. While that's a lot of rules, they could be easily generated with a small script in whatever scripting language you prefer. And, actually, there are not that many rules, particularly if you don't allow alphabetic and non-printing characters to be delimiters. This has the additional advantage that if you want Perl-like parenthetic delimiters (`#(Hello)` instead of `#(Hello(`), you can just modify the individual pattern to suit (as I've done below). [Note 1] Since all the actions are the same; it might be easier to use a macro for the action, making it easier to modify.

   ```c
     /* Ordinary punctuation */
   #:[^:]*:     { yylval = strndup(yytext + 2, yyleng - 3); return DELIMITED_STRING; }
   #:[^:]*:     { yylval = strndup(yytext + 2, yyleng - 3); return DELIMITED_STRING; }
   #![^!]*!     { yylval = strndup(yytext + 2, yyleng - 3); return DELIMITED_STRING; }
   #\.[^.]*\.   { yylval = strndup(yytext + 2, yyleng - 3); return DELIMITED_STRING; }
     /* Matched pairs */
   #<[^>]*>     { yylval = strndup(yytext + 2, yyleng - 3); return DELIMITED_STRING; }
   #\[[^]]*]    { yylval = strndup(yytext + 2, yyleng - 3); return DELIMITED_STRING; }
     /* Trap errors */
   #            { /* Report unmatched or invalid delimiter error */ }
   ```

   If I were writing a script to generate these rules, I would use hexadecimal escapes for all the delimiter characters rather than trying to figure out which ones needed escapes.

---

#### Notes:

1. Perl requires nested balanced parentheses in constructs like that. But you can't do that with regular expressions; if you wanted to reproduce Perl behaviour, you'd need to use some variation on one of the other suggestions. I'll try to revisit this answer later to address that feature.